# How to find a bug in ".emacs" or "init.el"?

Tags: debugging, emacs, initialization, elisp, config

Sometimes when I open Emacs, Emacs initialization fail.
That is because `.emacs` or `init.el` files have a bug. (My bugs often come from just mistyping.)

I want to find the bug in `.emacs` or `init.el`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I forgot to say this: I'll upvote or check-mark your question several days later. So don't worry about no check mark and no upvote.

Answer (score 21):

To find out what part of your init file (`~/.emacs`) is causing the behavior you see, **bisect** your init file **recursively**: First comment-out half, to see which half is responsible, then 3/4, to see which quarter is responsible,...

To comment out a region of text (e.g. succession of lines that you have selected), I recommend `comment-region` (which I bind to `C-x C-;`).  With a numeric prefix arg it uses that many `;` comment chars. With a plain prefix arg (`C-u`) it uncomments the region instead of commenting it.

You can also start Emacs with the command-line switch `--debug-init`. This will cause the debugger to open when an error is raised during Emacs startup, including while your init file is loaded. The debugger backtrace tells you which evaluation raised the error (which function was called), and it shows you which function called the function where the error was raised, which function called that one, and so on.

When you know which function is the problem, if you need to you can debug its evaluation by putting `(debug-on-entry 'THE-FUNCTION)` near the start of your init file. That will open the debugger when the function is entered instead of just showing what happened when the error was raised. You can then step through the debugger using `d` (or `c` to skip through a step), to see just what went wrong.

If you prefer to step through the function starting at some breakpoint, then copy the source code that defines the function to your init file, and insert `(debug)` at the position where you want the debugger to open.

As always, the Emacs manuals are your friends.  See, for instance, node `Checklist` in the Emacs manual and node `Invoking the Debugger` in the Elisp manual.

There is another debugger also, called `edebug`, which is also documented in the manuals.  Some people prefer it to `debug`.  (I prefer `debug`.)  Both are good.

Using the debugger is generally more informative if you have loaded Emacs Lisp source files rather than their byte-compiled versions.  If you start investigating a particular problem using the debugger, you might want to first load the `*.el` (not `*.elc`) file(s) in question.

Comment: `comment-dwim` is also very useful for (un)commenting regions. It is bound to `M-;` by default. It will comment out the region if it currently isn't commented out, and uncomment it if it is (without having to use a prefix argument).

Comment: See [**this help-gnu-emacs thread**](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-04/msg00602.html) for why `comment-region` is superior to `comment-dwim` for commenting and uncommmenting blocks of code.  In a nutshell: `comment-dwim` is multi-purpose; it does not specialize in region commenting but instead tries to do a little bit of everything.  And no, `comment-dwim` will not uncomment the region if it has both commented lines and uncommented lines.

Comment: Interesting read, thanks. Good thing I *didn't* say that `comment-dwim` was superior to `comment-region`, nor that it would handle regions that mix commented and uncommented lines correctly ;)

Comment: ;-)  Differing opinions about which is handier are good, not bad.

Comment: So many new things I just learned from the answer and comments! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Drew: This may be my bible when debugging elisp code. Great documentation thanks.

Comment: Bisecting the config may not help due to dependencies within your config. Just saying, otherwise its a very good tip!

Comment: @sjas: The same applies to any dependencies, if you need to dig into where they have a problem - recursively bisect *their* code. But if all you need to learn is *that* dependency XYZ has a problem, and not *where*, then report the problem to its maintainer.

Answer (score 16):

I've had great success with elisp bug hunter https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter.

The most common problems are unmatched parenthesis, loading-failed packages.:

> **Automated error hunting**
>
> If your Emacs init file signals an error during startup, but you don’t
>   know why, simply issue
>
> `M-x bug-hunter-init-file RET e`
>
> and The Bug Hunter will find it for you. Note that your init.el (or
>   .emacs) must be idempotent for this to work.
>
> **Interactive hunt**
>
> If Emacs starts up without errors but something is not working as it
>   should, invoke the same command, but choose the interactive option:
>
> `M-x bug-hunter-init-file RET i`
>
> The Bug Hunter will start a separate Emacs instance several times, and
>   then it will ask you each time whether that instance presented the
>   problem you have. After doing this about 5–12 times, you’ll be given
>   the results.

Answer (score 9):

You can debug your `.emacs` file like this: [Debugging a customization file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Debugging-a-customization-file.html)

> Start Emacs with the ‘-debug-init’ command-line option. This enables
>   the Emacs Lisp debugger before evaluating your .emacs file, and places
>   you in the debugger if something goes wrong. The top line in the
>   trace-back buffer will be the error message, and the second or third
>   line of that buffer will display the Lisp code from your .emacs file
>   that caused the problem.
>
> You can also evaluate an individual function or argument to a function
>   in your .emacs file by moving the cursor to the end of the function or
>   argument and typing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-last-sexp`).
>
> Use <kbd>C-h v</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-variable`) to check the value of variables
>   which you are trying to set or use.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add it's good to anticipate. The function below, coming from  [oremacs.com](http://oremacs.com/2015/03/05/testing-init-sanity/) allows to check the validity of our init file (or any other file) without starting up emacs:

```
(defun ora-test-emacs ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'async)
  (async-start
   (lambda () (shell-command-to-string
          "emacs --batch --eval \"
(condition-case e
    (progn
      (load \\\"~/.emacs\\\")
      (message \\\"-OK-\\\"))
  (error
   (message \\\"ERROR!\\\")
   (signal (car e) (cdr e))))\""))
   `(lambda (output)
      (if (string-match "-OK-" output)
          (when ,(called-interactively-p 'any)
            (message "All is well"))
        (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*startup error*")
        (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
        (insert output)
        (search-backward "ERROR!")))))
```

One can even add a Travis CI test.

ps: solutions summed up on [wikemacs](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/User's_Initialization_File#Debugging_the_Init_file).

Answer (score 2):

Some good advice has already been given. In particular, I think @Drew's response pretty much covers what you need to do.

I wanted to also mention that how you structure your config file can also help in tracking down problems. For example, grouping similar or related configuration options together can be very helpful.

However, the one thing which I found to be the most helpful was to break up my configuration into separate files. Essentially, my init.el file does nothing but setup some load-path settings so that my actual configuration code can be found and then just calls '''require to load each of the files.

In my .emacs.d directory, I have a directory called lisp and in that directory, I have a bunch of *.el files with names like init-org.el, init-clojure.el, init-javascript.el etc. In each of those files, I have the config settings relevant to the name i.e. org setup stuff in init-org.el, javascript stuff in init-javascript.el etc.

Each of these files ends with a 'provide' form i.e.

```
(provide 'init-org)
```

at the end of init-org.el and

```
(provide 'init-javascript)
```

at the end of init-javascript.el etc.

In my init.el file, I just have lines like

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "lisp" user-emacs-directory))

(require 'init-org)
(require 'init-javascript)
(require 'init-clojre)
```

The benefit of doing this is that it is now even easier to bisect my init file. I can just comment out the first half of the require statements - many fewer lines.

the other benefit is that sometimes, if I'm having problems with some config, but it isn't really related to the work I need to do now, I can just comment out that require and get back to work. For example, if I am doing some clojure coding, but having some error when starting emacs due to a problem in my javascript setup, then I can just comment out the (require 'init-javascript) line and I'm good to go.