# Emacs - *Backtrace* won't open on error

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I'm trying to get Emacs 24.3.1 to open the `*Backtrace*` buffer on errors, but nothing I try seems to do the trick. This includes evaluating `(setq debug-on-error t)`, running the `toggle-debug-on-error` command, and verifying that there is nothing in my `.emacs` that could be influencing it.

Errors always get printed to the mini-buffer, but even when I manually open `*Backtrace`, it doesn't show any of the debugging info.

Any thoughts on how I can restore the expected functionality?

Comment: Seeing as you've accepted Drew's answer, what did the problem turn out to be?

Comment: The *cause* of the error still isn't clear, but as I explained in response to his answer, evoking Emacs from the terminal resulted in normal behavior being restored. From the looks of it, it may have to do with the fact that Ubuntu contains a copy of Emacs that can be launched from Unity. However, I also compiled Emacs from source - this is the copy of the application that runs from terminal. Both copies are the same version, but one shows up as being compiled for Debian and the other shows up as being compiled for "unknown" Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine that, as Emacs 24.3 has been available for quite a while, many people use `debug-on-error` with it, with no problem.

You do not provide a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` (i.e., not init file).  If you can give us such a recipe to reproduce the problem then we can try to address that.  Unless you do that, we can only assume that the problem comes from your init file (or from some code that it loads).

Without knowledge of that code, we cannot really help much, except to suggest ways to find the problem introduced by your init file.  [How to find a bug in .emacs or init.el](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957/729907) should help with that.

Comment: My init file is empty - I made sure to rename it for troubleshooting this issue. I've been running Emacs from the Ubuntu application (through the Unity launcher), but when I launch it from terminal with `emacs -Q` it works fine! So, it seems the issue is resolved, but do you have any idea why this might be?

Sample recipe:

`$ emacs -Q`
(in Emacs:)
type `(this shouldn't evaluate)`, then `C-x C-e`

Comment: I assume you meant to add `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before trying to eval that sexp.  Doing that raises the debugger in buffer `*Backtrace*`, for me.  I know nothing about the Unity launcher, but perhaps it is related to the problem you see. Do you see problems for Emacs to open other windows, besides `*Backtrace*`?  If no one here has a good idea then you consider filing an Emacs bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Emacs developers will likely be able to get to the bottom of this.  But wait a bit, to see if someone has some insight about this here -- e.g. maybe some Unity expert.

Answer (score 9):

I will just point out one thing that resolved a previous instance of the same problem. On error my emacs went to the *Backtrace*. Since I had never seen it before, I killed it. After that, on error I would just get the error message in the ECHO area. To bring back the *Backtrace* buffer I did `M+x debug` once. After doing that, I get the *Backtrace* buffer on every error.