# emacs vc mode checkin

Tags: svn, emacs, version-control

Perhaps I am going mad. The last time I used to use the VC mode to commit a checkin message to a modified file everything worked.

The scenario:

I modify some source file. I do "C-x v v" and it pops up a "*vc-log*" buffer allowing me to enter a message. So, this is what it looks like:

```
JIRA-TICKET-NUMBER: xyz
SUMMARY: added a useful comment
REVIEWER: richard.stallman
MERGED: -
```

Now, I press "C-c c" which then says everything is complete.

So, I go to shell, and do "svn up && svn log --limit 1" . However, I notice that the checkin comment has been vastly truncated. And the svn log only shows the first line:

```
JIRA-TICKET-NUMBER: xyz
```

and nothing else.

It seems like it is truncating and treating the newline as end-of.

But, I am 99% sure that I was able to do multiple lines but a few months ago.

What to try?

Cheers.

Comment: The first thing to try is to start emacs with the -Q parameter, so that non of your config is loaded. If the problem does not occur then then it's something in your config and you can try bisecting it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957/265069

Comment: Hi, thank you so far.
I can confirm that with emacs -Q the issue still persists. I only get the first line of the \*vc-log\* and the rest is truncated.

Comment: Then I guess the next step is thinking about what changed since the last time when it worked. Did you upgrade emacs? Did you upgrade svn? Did you change something else on your system which could affect this? If you find what changed then you may be closer to finding where things went broke.

Comment: I am afraid I am completely stumped. I have tried a previous version of emacs which I may have been using 24.1, rather than 24.3 - I have tried all permutations - including having each version with -q and not and in ALL instances the checkin comment truncates the rest of the message only to the first line.

I cannot remember how I managed to get multiply newlines in a checkin comment.

It kind of makes sense though, if you do 

`svn ci -m ticket-nu\n
summary:\n
reviewe: fdfd
last:
`

this will not work - for obvious reasons. You must put quotations around the whole thing to allow multi lines.

Comment: Well, I don't use svn, but multiline comments should work I guess. Ask the gurus on the emacs help list. They may know what's up and some of them may even have tried this with svn: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help

Comment: Yes, thank you:
http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help/cutoff=101518

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre issue solved:

Yes, I was running two machines with exactly the same processor instruction set. The same version of emacs; non-different el and elc files. The same version of SVN! Everything.

The only difference was this: On the machine which - yesterday (i.e. before this was solved) - produced multiple lines I had - on my $PATH - a location which pointed to a directory containing a windows shortcut named svn.exe; it pointed to the actual binary used. Now, on the machine which did not allow multi-line I did not have this location on my $PATH. Instead it just had the location of the directory containing the actual svn binary (though, this was also the case for the machine allowing multi-line, but because the directory containing the shortcut preceded the "actual" binary-directory, the shortcut gets accessed first; proved by using "which svn").

So, for some reason when using the svn binary directly I could not do multi-line. But, when using the shortcut which points to that binary anyway multi-line was not allowed. I just always treated windows shortcuts like symbolic links, but perhaps something else is going on here.

Anyway, solved.