# Overwrite Behavior in Emacs24 Python Outline Overwrite Mode

Tags: python, ubuntu, emacs, overwrite

I am using emacs24 on ubuntu 14.04 to write some python code. I recently upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 and emacs23 and it appears that the new python mode in emacs is called "py outl". I have tried researching this mode but cannot find my particular issue.

I want to overwrite some values in my code using the "py outl ovwrt" mode (I just hit the insert key). However, when typing the replacement values in this mode, emacs behaves strangely.

Say I have:

```
y = 'abcdefghij'
```

and using overwrite I want to change it to:

```
y = '12345fghij'
```

What actually happens is I get:

```
y = '1b2d3f4h5j'
```

I am only entering the numbers in sequentially and not moving the cursor myself. Emacs is moving the cursor over an extra character every time. Maybe this behavior is expected in this new python mode, but it's not what I'm used to nor what I want it to do. Is there a particular reason emacs is doing this? It's only happening with *.py files. In normal text files I get what I expect with overwrite mode.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

**UPDATE:** I followed a combination of Andreas Röhler's and Thomas's advice below in which I ran `emacs -Q python-mode` and my problem was not reproduced. I then bisected my `~/.emacs` file and nothing there was causing my problem.

I did solve my problem with a somewhat random combination of uninstalling and reinstalling Emacs 24, trying a new python mode, and finally deleting the new python mode directory from `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`. I admit that this probably isn't the best way to go about it, but now the mode that shows in my emacs window is `Python` as it used to.

Unfortunately, this means I am still not sure what exactly was causing my problem, though I suspect it might have something to do with my upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you observe.

The mode-line information you see ("py outl") hints at the fact that you're using [Andreas Röhler's python-mode](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode) which as far as I know is not the one that is shipped with standard GNU Emacs. (At least when I start emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, I get a different mode-line. However, when I download Röhler's python mode, I do get "py outl" as well.) Note that the "outl" part refers to `outline-minor-mode` (see paragraph 4 on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Mode.html) page). Similarly, the "ovwrt" part indicates that [`overwrite-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Overwrite-mode.html) is active.

I suggest that you start emacs with the `-Q` option to check if the behavior persists. If not, then something in your configuration might cause the effect your see. [Bisecting your `~/.emacs` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957/261142) is one way to find the perpetrator.

Comment: Thanks. Just let me add: the mode is directed by Barry Warsaw and got code from a lot of people - while contributing a lot also, right.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce, overwrite-mode works nicely with current python-mode.el.
Assume some "smart"-mode being the cupable.

As Thomas suggested: go into directory where python-mode.el resides: emacs -Q python-mode.el. M-x evaluate-buffer RET loading it. Then try again.

Please file bug-reports at

https://gitlab.com/groups/python-mode-devs/issues

or

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: Ah, yes, good idea to actually load the mode, which `-Q` would otherwise inhibit! I forgot that in my own answer.